# Create class default api Restful nodejs with Typescript

Tags: node.js, typescript

I am new in nodejs with typescript, and I want create a class with methods that recive the model mongoose as params and make basics request to database like, save, find, findOneById, findOneByIdAndUpadate etc

Here my model below

```
import { Document, Schema, model } from 'mongoose'

export interface ISimulator extends Document{
  name: string;
  speedways: string[];
  categorys: string[];
  cars: string[];
}

const schema = new Schema({
  name: { type: String, required: true },
  speedways: [
    { type: String }
  ],
  categorys: [
    { type: String }
  ],
  cars: [
    { type: String }
  ]
})

export const Simulator = model<ISimulator>('simulator', schema)
```

What I want Its samething like this

```
import { model } from 'mongoose'

export default class DefaultRestful {
    getall( mdl: model ) {
        const getall = mdl.find()
        res.status(200).send(getall)
    }
}
```

but a recive the errors " model refers to a value, but is being used as a type here.

How Can I make this work?

Comment: You are using a value as a type, which you cannot do. You probably want something like `getall( mdl: typeof model ) {`

Comment: but we still haven't arrived at a solution